# Styling Issue with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, styles

i have got a problem on:
http://tinyurl.com/7rb66t4

it is basically this template:
http://www.display-inline.fr/demo/constellation/template/login.php

but the template works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.
Just IE makes problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing the doctype attribute on the top of your file

Comment: it should be at the very top of your page